# for i in rangeについての質問

Tags: python

コード

```
l=["Mon","tue","Wed","sat"]

for i in range(len(l)):
    print(i)   
    l[i] = l[i].upper()
print(i)
print(l)
```

上のコードにおいて、1つ目のprint(i)では結果が「0,1,2,3」と出ますが、2つ目のprint(i)では結果が「3」とのみ出ます。この二つの違いはなんでしょうか？

結果を以下に示します。よろしくお願いします。

```
0
1
2
3
3
['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'SAT']
```

Comment: 2つ目の`print(i)`の結果がどうなるだろうと予想していたかを追記すると、それに沿った回答が出やすくなるでしょう。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

結論から言えば２つの「print(i)」に違いはありません。

```
for i in range(len(l)):
   ★iの中に0から配列lのサイズまでループする。つまりiは0,1,2,3が入ってくる
   print(i)
   ★iの内容を標準出力に出力する。前述の通り、iは0,1,2,3とループ内で変更させるので
    0
    1
    2
    3 
      と表示される。この時iの値は最終的に3が入っていることに注意
print(i) 
 ★前述の通りループは終了し、i=3のままこの処理を実行するので、3が出力される。
面白いのは、iの変数スコープってforの中で切れてないんですね。。。エラー返してくれたほうがわかりやすいのに。。
```

Answer (score 2):

違い：ループの内か外か

１つ目の print(i) は for ループの内側にある。→ ループに伴って i = 0, 1, 2, 3

２つ目の print(i) は for ループの外側にある。→ ループが止った最後の状態の i がそのまま使われる。